# Create this query

Tags: php, yii

Covert createCommand to CDbCriteria.

How create this query with **CDbCriteria** yii?

```
SELECT SUM(f.mablagh) as kol,k.code,k.name,m.name AS mName,m.code AS mCode
FROM T1 AS f
LEFT JOIN T2 AS k ON k.code=f.kCode
LEFT JOIN T3 As m ON m.code=k.main
GROUP BY k.main
```

T1 model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'kCode0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'T2', 'kCode'),
    );
}
```

T2 model:

```
return array(
       'main' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'T3', 'mymain'),
    );
```

in other words , I want convert this code:

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('SUM(f.mablagh) as kol,k.code,k.name,m.name AS mName,m.code AS mCode')
                ->from('T1 AS f')
                ->join('T2 AS k' ,'k.code=f.kCode')
                ->join('T3 AS m' ,'m.code=k.main')
                ->group('k.main')
                ->queryAll();
```

To:

```
$criteria   = new CDbCriteria;
.
.
.
.
$result = T1::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use criteria, then you can use it without any other models relationships:

```
$criteria   = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = "SUM(t.mablagh) as kol,k.code,k.name,m.name AS mName,m.code AS mCode";
$criteria->join = "LEFT JOIN T2 AS k ON k.code=t.kCode LEFT JOIN T3 AS m ON m.code=k.main";
$criteria->group = "k.main";
$result = T1::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: thank but on **print_r($result)** data T2,T3 not exist!

Comment: You'll need to change it to the table names. Or do T2::model()->tableName() if you're using classes.

Comment: It is possible to explain a little

Comment: Well, are T2 and T3 tables? What do you don't understand?